# Is it insecure to make HTTP requests to a REST API in my program code

Tags: rest, security

I'm currently using a REST API to communicate with one of my external installed Docker container. Is this a secure method to use an API because it looks for me like an equivalent to DNS poisoning. If not, what are the alternatives if there is only a REST API?

```
My program => REST API call via a HTTP library => Docker container
```

Comment: Calling a REST API can be secure and it can be insecure, but it's impossible to know without more details. This has nothing to do with DNS poisoning.

Comment: I know that it has nothing to do with DNS poisoning. I think the principle could be same. If I send a request to a REST API then it could lead me to a fake URL.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with fake URL Jan, or what your point is exactly.

Comment: REST is a common way these days for services communication, it's being used by the biggest corporates. Of course it can be exploited like any other method, but I wouldn't go with a general statement that it's not secured.